# Are the Hamiltonian and spatial diffeomorphism constraints satisfied at all times for GR?

Tags: general-relativity, constrained-dynamics, adm-formalism

The ADM formulation of GR allows the Einstein equations to be recast as an initial value problem. According to Sec 3.3 of [these notes](https://saalburg.aei.mpg.de/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2017/03/giulini.pdf) the outline of the procedure is as follows:

1. Pick a 3-metric $h_{ij}(x)$ and an extrinsic curvature $K_{ij}(x)$ as initial data on a initial time slice $t=0$. Ensure that they satisfy the Hamiltonian and spatial diffeomorphism constraints, $\mathcal H(x)=0$ and $C_i(x)=0$ respectively.
2. Pick arbitrary lapse and shift functions $\alpha(t,x)$ and $\beta_i(t,x)$. Then evolve $h_{ij}$ and $K_{ij}$ according to the evolution equations. The evolution equations are 1st order in time derivatives, so the initial data determines the solution uniquely.

This gives us the metric and extrinsic curvature as functions of space and time: $h_{ij}(t,x)$ and $K_{ij}(t,x)$. My question is whether the Hamiltonian and spatial diffeomorphism constraints are satisfied at all times (they are by design satisfied at $t=0$) and how one would go about proving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we write the 4-constraints collectively as $C_\mu(x)=0$, then what we're trying to verify is whether $\{C_\mu(x),H\}=0$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian. The Hamiltonian itself is the sum of all constraints:
$$H=\int d^3x~\alpha^\mu(x) C_\mu(x)$$
where $\alpha^\mu(x)$ are the lapse and shift functions written collectively.
The Poisson brackets between the constraints is given by (see https://inspirehep.net/literature/73654 for example)
\begin{align}
\{C_0(x),C_0(x')\}&=(C_i(x)+C_i(x'))\partial^i \delta(x-x')\\
\{C_i(x),C_0(x')\}&=C_0(x)\partial_i \delta(x-x')\\
\{C_i(x),C_j(x')\}&=C_i(x')\partial_j \delta(x-x')+C_j(x)\partial_i \delta(x-x')
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\{C_0(x),H\}&= \partial_i(\alpha^i C_0)+C_i\partial^i\alpha_0+\partial^i(C_i\alpha_0)\\
\{C_i(x),H\}&=C_0\partial_i\alpha_0+\partial_j(C_i\alpha^j)+C_j\partial_i\alpha^j
\end{align}
Since $C_{\mu}(x)=0$ on the initial slice, we have $\{C_\mu(x),H\}=0$ as expected.